# How to evaluate function of two variables with different x and y vectors

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I've been trying to evaluate a function in matlab. I want my x vector to go from 0 to 1000 and my y vector to go from 0 to 125. They should both have a length of 101.
The equation to be evaluated is z(x,y) = a*y + b*x, with a=10 and b=20.

```
a = 10;
b = 20;
n = 101;
dx = 10; % Interval length
dy = 1.25; 
x = zeros(1,n);
y = zeros(1,n);
z = zeros(n,n);
for i = 1:n;
    x(i) = dx*(i-1);
    y(i) = dy*(i-1);
    for j = 1:n;
        z(i,j) = a*dy*(j-1) + b*dx*(j-1);
    end
end
```

I get an answer, but I don't know if I did it correctly with the indices in the nested for loop?

Comment: Do you want x to increase along one matrix dimension, and y along the other? If so, your code is not correct. You want to do `x(i) = dx*(i-1)` and `y(j) = dy*(j-1)`, then `z(i,j) = a*y(j) + b*x(i)`.

Comment: Create `x` and `y` using `linspace`, then you can use `meshgrid`: `[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y)` followed by `Z =  a*Y+b*X`.

Comment: @obchardon: you no longer need `meshgrid`, there's implicit singleton expansion now. You can just write `z = a*y + b*x.'`.

Answer (score 1):

See MATLAB's [linspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) function.

```
a=10;
b=20;
n=101;
x=linspace(0,1000,n);
y=linspace(0,125,n);
z=a*y+b*x;
```

This is easier and takes care of the interval spacing for you. From the linspace documentation,

> y = linspace(x1,x2,n) generates n points. The spacing between the points is (x2-x1)/(n-1).

Edit:
As others have pointed out, my solution above makes a vector, not a matrix which the OP seems to want. As @obchardon pointed out, you can use `meshgrid` to make that 2D grid of x and y points to generate a matrix of z. Updated approached would be:

```
a=10;
b=20;
n=101;
x=linspace(0,1000,n);
y=linspace(0,125,n);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z=a*Y+b*X;
```

(you may swap the order of `x` and `y` depending on if you want each variable along the row or column of `z`.)

Comment: Your answer would be a vector and not a matrix, I think, as @obchardon pointed out in the comment, you should use `meshgrid` or any other approach to generate all possible combinations ....

Comment: `meshgrid` is not necessary, just write `z = a*y + b*x.'`. For older versions of MATLAB, you'd need to do what with `bsxfun`. `meshgrid` is more expensive because of the large intermediate arrays.